# Append codes to a select element on the fly

Tags: javascript, html, append

I have the following code being generated by the Google Translate Toolkit in my webpage:

```
<select class="goog-te-combo">
 <option value="en">English</option>
 <option value="af">Afrikaans</option>
 <option value="sq">Albanian</option>
```

What I have been trying desperately to create is a script that would allow me to convert:

```
<option value="en">English</option>
                to
<option value="en" **style="background: red;"**>English</option>
```

The script would read the *Value* attribute of the *Option* tag and then append a custom code accordingly to the HTML on the fly just like - If *value=en* , add *background:red* or something like that. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: append what to where in the HTML?

Comment: You're not making sense, man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the JQuery answer Florian mentioned was coming.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var language = '';
var color = '';
$("#myselect option").each(function() {
    language = $(this).attr('value');
    switch (language) {
    case 'en':
        color = 'red';
        break;
    case 'fr':
        color = 'blue';
        break;
    default:
        color = "black";
        break;
    }
    $(this).attr('style', "color:" + color + ";");
});

$("#myselect").change(function() {
    $(this).css('color', $(this).find("option:selected").css('color'));
});

});
```

You can add more colors to the case statement if you'd like. Also, make sure you give your select statment an ID of myselect or anything you want, as long as you change the JQuery.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LBFBd/

Comment: Please have a look here - http://htmlgeeks.net/translate/abc.html    It does not seem to work. I must be doing something wrong. I am very new to JS.

Comment: Hey @Matt , Can you please take a look at this page - http://htmlgeeks.net/translate/try.html
Why is it not working on the Select Box on the right while it works on the left one?

Comment: Probably because you can't have two objects with the same Id. switch the #myselected to a .myselected. Then change the Id='myselected' to class='myselected' on both of the drop downs and in the jquery code.

Comment: I dont have the #myselected id on the page if you look closely. I am using the goog-te-combo class to do the operation. But still it only wokrs on the left one, very strange!!

Answer (score 0):

Some will provide a jQuery answer, here is a vanilla js answer:

Considering the following HTML:

```
<form name="my">
    <select name="sl">
        <option name="en" value="en">
    </select>
</form>
```

Then this JS will do:

```
document.forms.my.options['en'].style.background = 'red'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to do something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.goog-te-combo').change(function{
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    if(selectedValue == 'en')
     {
      $('.goog-te-combo option:selected').css('background','Red');
     }
    });
});
```

PS : Not tested, but I believe should work